# Long delay loading my wordpress web site running Apache 2, worker, fastcgi and mysql on linux

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, apache

I am running Apache2 worker with fastgi and mysql on ubuntu. I have recently seen the page load time increase by 20 seconds and am trying to determine the cause. I have strace'd apache2 and do not see any obvious delays. On webpagetest.org, I can see the 20 second delay after loading the .js files and before downloading the first image. You can see the results of the weppagetest.org here:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150812_8J_SP4/1/details/

I am at a loss on how to troubleshoot this further. Can anyone please help point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out. The issue was caused by DNS lookup failures because a domain (that I own, the predecessor to the one I use now) was being referred to. That old domain had recently expired. I scraped through Wordpress and changed any reference to this old domain and now the web site has nice response time.

Here are the updated WebPageTest results:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150812_Y5_12AR/1/details/

Still some more tuning to do, but far better than before.

Thanks
Jack